# A method to calculate related float values in c++

Tags: c++

> I'm not sure if this the right place to ask and I'm certainly not sure
>   if this has been answered elsewhere so don't shoot me if it is. Maybe
>   I'm not using the right words when searching.
>
> **I'm trying to create a generic float method to calculate related values in c++ but limited by their min, max values.** Math isn't my
>   thing so I'd love some help at this stage.
>
> **To the point:** Let's say that we have a float variable named "***health***" that could get any value from **0** to **100**. We also
>   have a second float variable named "***walkingSpeed***" that can get
>   any value from **100** to **200**.
>
> I need a method to calculate and return what "walkingSpeed" would be in relation to "*health*" while always taking in account the min and
>   max values of these two variables ( if Health = HealthMax then
>   walkingSpeed = walking SpeedMax etc ). I tried to work with % but I
>   couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?
>
> Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:
Generic Method based on @Felipe 's suggestion:**

```
/*
* Returns valueY based on a relative value X
*
* @RelXMin - Minimum relative value
* @RelXMax - Maximum relative value
* @relX - Relative value
* @valueYMin - Minimum value
* @valueYMax - Maximum value
* #bInverse - set true if the y is inverse related to x
*/
float calcRelativeFloatValue(float RelXMin, float RelXMax, float relX, float valueYMin, float valueYMax, bool bInverse)
{
    float xRange, yRelative;

    xRange = RelXMax - RelXMin;
    yRelative = (valueYMax - valueYMin) / xRange;

    if (bInverse)
    {
        return valueYMax - (yRelative * relX);
    }
    return valueYMin + (yRelative * relX) ;
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, but more about math.

Comment: It appears you want `float estimated_walking_speed = health + 100;` This will give 100 when health is 0, and 200 when health is 100.

Comment: True that @MSalters. As pointed out I wasn't sure if this should be asked here yet I always prefer to work with fellow programmers. My apologies.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, that's true indeed. I'm trying to break it down to a generic method though like let's say:

float Value(float valueMin, float valueMax, float relValue, float relValueMin, float relValueMax);

Comment: This is one of those cases where it's probably hard to search for the right ideas if you don't know the area. You might want to try searching for: linear interpolation and splines, if you are trying to fit a function from a set of pre-existing data points then you might want to look at linear regression or some other form of [regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking for [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

The two known points are the minimum and the maximum values. So you can use a general interpolation function like this (just the equation from wikipedia written as code):

```
float interpolate(float x, float x_0, float x_1, float y_0, float y_1) {
  return y_0*(y_1-y_0)*(x-x_0)/(x_1/x_0);
}
```

Your example would then be

```
walkingSpeed=interpolate(health, minHealth, maxHealth, minWalkingSpeed, maxWalkingSpeed);
```

Comment: "Linear Interpolation" is indeed what the website suggested in the first place but yeah... This is what I get for studying c++ using non English books... Thank you very much everyone!!!

Answer (score 1):

In this *specific* case, the task is pretty trivial:

```
float estimated_walking_speed = health + 100;
```

For the more generic task of mapping a value in one range to the corresponding value in some other range, you'd be looking at something like this:

```
auto input_range = input_upper - input_lower;
auto relative_input_loc = (input_value - input_lower) / input_range;

auto output_range = output_upper - output_lower;
auto output = output_lower + (relative_input_loc * output_range);
```

[This is open to simplification/optimization--I'm writing it all out to keep it as understandable as possible.]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
float calculateSpeed(float minHealth, float maxHealth, float currentHealth, float minSpeed, float maxSpeed) {
  float healthLength = maxHealth - minHealth;
  float speedPerHealth = (maxSpeed - minSpeed) / healthLength;

  float partialSpeed = speedPerHealth * currentHealth;
  float currentSpeed = partialSpeed + minSpeed;

  return currentSpeed;
}
```